# Who was this girl?

Tags: knowledge, story

In a country full of ancient trees known as the Republic of the Golden Bear, in what would have been the 8th month of the year, a girl was born. Victor, her Papa, went into the capital to announce her birth. Standing in the square where marriages were declared, he cleared his throat. "Ahem!" He held up a picture of her to show his pride, "A kid's arrival!" She was wrapped in a blanket decorated with images of fruits and flowers: acacia, iris, manna, a fern.

Who was she?

Comment: "Golden Bear" (as per Nautilus' answer) and "Victor Papa" make me think of a very special 'girl', and I really wanted her to be the answer. However, I couldn't find any link to the other clues :'(

Comment: @BarryPoppins you might well be along the right lines. rot13(Gurer ner n pbhcyr bs nantenzf va gurer juvpu zvtug uryc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think she is:

> Kamala Devi Harris

Thanks, Vicky, for the hint: her name is

> the anagram of Ahem A Kid's Arrival

and of course she is the

> VP (Victor Papa) of the United States.

She was born in the month of:

> October, which in the Roman calendar was the 8th month. I don't know why I didn't spot it earlier - for some reason I misread it as January in her Wikipedia biography...

and she is the first in her role to be of

> Asian-African-American heritage (an anagram of Acacia Iris Manna A Fern)

Comment: rot13(Lbh tbg vg! V'yy npprcg lbhe nafjre bapr lbh'ir svtherq bhg ng yrnfg bar zber bs gur pyhrf gung ner uvqqra va gurer... :-))

Comment: Harsh but fair :) I'll do my best

Comment: @Vicky, I found another one: does this suffice?

Comment: Yes! Well done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Her name is probably...

> **Sonoma**, California. [Victor Prudon is the first known person to draw sketches of Sonoma, a city in California](https://www.askart.com/artist/Victor_Prudon/11006394/Victor_Prudon.aspx).

Comment: Interesting idea! However, not the right answer I'm afraid.

Comment: rot13(Gur "Pnyvsbeavn" cneg bs lbhe nafjre vf evtug, ohg V nz ybbxvat sbe gur anzr bs n crefba nf gur nafjre gb gur chmmyr.)